# algorithm to deal with series of values

Tags: objective-c, algorithm, math, time-series

With a series with a `START`, `INCREMENT`, and `MAX`:

```
START = 100
INCREMENT = 30
MAX = 315

e.g. 100, 130, 160, 190, 220, 250, 280, 310
```

Given an arbitrary number `X` return:

- the values remaining in the series where the first value is `>= X`
- the offset `Y` (catch up amount needed to get from X to first value of the series).

Example

```
In:
START = 100
INCREMENT = 30
MAX = 315
X = 210

Out:
Y = 10
S = 220, 250, 280, 310
```

UPDATE -- From MBo answer:

```
float max = 315.0;
float inc = 30.0;
float start = 100.0;
float x = 210.0;

float k0 =  ceil( (x-start) / inc) ;
float k1 =  floor( (max - start) / inc) ;

for (int i=k0; i<=k1; i++)
{
    NSLog(@" output: %d: %f", i, start + i * inc);
}


output: 4: 220.000000
output: 5: 250.000000
output: 6: 280.000000
output: 7: 310.000000
```

MBo integer approach will be nicer.

Comment: Why the -1? Not a well-formed question? I ask because I prefer not to get dinged in the future.

Comment: May suppose - because own efforts have not been shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

School math:

```
Start + k0 * Inc >= X
k0 * Inc >= X - Start
k0 >= (X - Start) / Inc
```

Programming math:

```
k0 = Ceil(1.0 * (X - Start) / Inc)
k1 = Floor(1.0 * (Max - Start) / Inc)
for i = k0 to k1  (including both ends)
  output Start + i * Inc
```

Integer math:

```
k0 = (X - Start + Inc - 1) / Inc      //such integer division makes ceiling
k1 = (Max - Start) / Inc              //integer division makes flooring
for i = k0 to k1  (including both ends)
  output Start + i * Inc
```

Example:

```
 START = 100  
 INCREMENT = 30  
 MAX = 315  
 X = 210  

k0 = Ceil((210 - 100) / 30) = Ceil(3.7) = 4
k1 = Floor((315 - 100) / 30) = Floor(7.2) = 7
first 100 + 4 * 30 = 220
last 100 + 7 * 30 = 310
```

Comment: I applied this against my Example 1 and the values where as follows
output: 3: 190
output: 4: 220
output: 5: 250
output: 6: 280

Comment: Perhaps you changed ceil and floor operations. See example

Comment: I updated my question, can you look at the code I am using?

Comment: Both expressions should be calculated with **float** division 1.0 * (x-start) / inc or (float) (x-start) / inc - don't know objective-c syntax.  -1-off for the second expression is due to `i<k1` condition  - should be `i<=k1`

Comment: And I've added pure integer arithmetics

Comment: Thank you. I never would have been able to do this. I will use the integer version. I have a similar problem and will study this to try to solve. This is far outside my competency. I disagree about -1 for the question itself but I defer to you.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the inequation

```
X <= S + K.I <= M
```

This is equivalent to

```
K0 = Ceil((X - S) / I) <= K <= Floor((M - S) / I) = K1
```

and

```
Y = X - (S + K0.I).
```

Note that it is possible to have `K0 > K1`, and there is no solution.